# How to get a compatible time stamp for file io?

Tags: java, android, date, file-io, timestamp

I am writing a method to save a file to the SD card on android. I want to have this as the format "description_code_uniqueTimeStamp.png".

I have tried several date and time formats but receive errors when I try to write the file as its invalid format. Probable due to : or .

Can anyone provide me with a solution to a unique time stamp (down to seconds should be ok) which will be valid for a filename?

Thanks

Comment: please clarify "unique timestamp" (also, see system.currenttimemillis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String prefix = "description_code_";
final String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
String filename = prefix + sdf.format(new Date(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the timestamp string and then run that String through an encoder that takes out characters that are not allowed for example...

```
public static String encodeString(String string) {
        if (string != null) {
            string.replace("&", "&amp;");
            string.replace("<", "&lt;");
            string.replace(">", "&gt;");
            string.replace("\"", "&quot;");
            string.replace("'", "&apos;");
        }
        return string;
    }
```